# How to change the soft keys bar into a minimized version?

Tags: android

On a phone without hardware buttons, the soft keys bar looks like:

[image]

In some app (e.g. the browser), the soft keys bar is minimized and more screen space is available:

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Set your theme to be fullscreen, then build the controls yourself. The Up/Down arrow toggles the fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to try to hide that bar, even if this could be done on some devices. It's obvious on most devices these keys are more like hardward key even accept touch input.